# Redis cluster unavailable while switching slave to master

Tags: redis, redis-cluster

I'm facing now situation at redis cluster (v 6.0.6, three slaves and three masters) - cluster becomes totally unavailable while one node is switching from slave to master.

One node at one server, another five nodes at another. Every node contains approx 50gb of data. Both servers have enough RAM to handle all this data.

Logs from #1 node:

```
4049748:M 05 Feb 2022 10:51:17.875 # Configuration change detected. Reconfiguring myself as a replica of cceb31e25d09e517b13d02a7afda01ca7c600dbe
4049748:S 05 Feb 2022 10:51:17.875 # Connection with replica client id #49754369 lost.
4049748:S 05 Feb 2022 10:51:17.875 * Before turning into a replica, using my own master parameters to synthesize a cached master: I may be able to synchronize with the new master with just a partial transfer.
4049748:S 05 Feb 2022 10:51:18.258 * Connecting to MASTER 172.16.0.1:6380
4049748:S 05 Feb 2022 10:51:18.258 * MASTER <-> REPLICA sync started
4049748:S 05 Feb 2022 10:51:18.258 * Non blocking connect for SYNC fired the event.
4049748:S 05 Feb 2022 10:51:18.259 * Master replied to PING, replication can continue...
4049748:S 05 Feb 2022 10:51:18.259 * Trying a partial resynchronization (request c2b950c078cdd48f345f855a154a99ff8d83f56d:2276202457008).
4049748:S 05 Feb 2022 10:51:20.366 * Full resync from master: b699d18495ae14e792a6dc09c9b413831b5d1951:2276203677470
4049748:S 05 Feb 2022 10:51:20.366 * Discarding previously cached master state.
4049748:S 05 Feb 2022 10:51:22.303 * MASTER <-> REPLICA sync: receiving streamed RDB from master with EOF to parser
4049748:S 05 Feb 2022 10:51:22.303 * MASTER <-> REPLICA sync: Flushing old data
4049748:S 05 Feb 2022 10:51:30.219 * MASTER <-> REPLICA sync: Loading DB in memory
4049748:S 05 Feb 2022 10:51:30.219 * Loading RDB produced by version 6.0.6
4049748:S 05 Feb 2022 10:51:30.219 * RDB age 8 seconds
4049748:S 05 Feb 2022 10:51:30.219 * RDB memory usage when created 56745.49 Mb
4049748:S 05 Feb 2022 11:01:45.652 * MASTER <-> REPLICA sync: Finished with success
4049748:S 05 Feb 2022 11:01:47.880 * Background append only file rewriting started by pid 3054262
4049748:S 05 Feb 2022 11:07:56.301 * AOF rewrite child asks to stop sending diffs.
3054262:C 05 Feb 2022 11:07:56.301 * Parent agreed to stop sending diffs. Finalizing AOF...
3054262:C 05 Feb 2022 11:07:56.301 * Concatenating 248.03 MB of AOF diff received from parent.
3054262:C 05 Feb 2022 11:07:57.307 * SYNC append only file rewrite performed
3054262:C 05 Feb 2022 11:07:59.858 * AOF rewrite: 2231 MB of memory used by copy-on-write
4049748:S 05 Feb 2022 11:08:02.165 * Background AOF rewrite terminated with success
4049748:S 05 Feb 2022 11:08:02.167 * Residual parent diff successfully flushed to the rewritten AOF (1.39 MB)
4049748:S 05 Feb 2022 11:08:02.167 * Background AOF rewrite finished successfully
```

Logs from #2 node:

```
3829405:S 05 Feb 2022 10:51:16.248 * FAIL message received from 83dcf2551f9652e6f6f79a2d38348c6c16949f25 about fc8e0258e3700c5fde1e3c0487ac1841718db33a
3829405:S 05 Feb 2022 10:51:16.266 # Start of election delayed for 765 milliseconds (rank #0, offset 2276202456934).
3829405:S 05 Feb 2022 10:51:17.067 # Starting a failover election for epoch 114.
3829405:S 05 Feb 2022 10:51:17.070 # Failover election won: I'm the new master.
3829405:S 05 Feb 2022 10:51:17.070 # configEpoch set to 114 after successful failover
3829405:M 05 Feb 2022 10:51:17.070 # Connection with master lost.
3829405:M 05 Feb 2022 10:51:17.070 * Caching the disconnected master state.
3829405:M 05 Feb 2022 10:51:17.070 * Discarding previously cached master state.
3829405:M 05 Feb 2022 10:51:17.070 # Setting secondary replication ID to c2b950c078cdd48f345f855a154a99ff8d83f56d, valid up to offset: 2276202456935. New replication ID is b699d18495ae14e792a6dc09c9b413831b5d1951
3829405:M 05 Feb 2022 10:51:18.116 * Clear FAIL state for node fc8e0258e3700c5fde1e3c0487ac1841718db33a: master without slots is reachable again.
3829405:M 05 Feb 2022 10:51:18.261 * Replica 172.16.0.3:6384 asks for synchronization
3829405:M 05 Feb 2022 10:51:18.261 * Partial resynchronization not accepted: Requested offset for second ID was 2276202457008, but I can reply up to 2276202456935
3829405:M 05 Feb 2022 10:51:18.261 * Delay next BGSAVE for diskless SYNC
3829405:M 05 Feb 2022 10:51:20.367 * Starting BGSAVE for SYNC with target: replicas sockets
3829405:M 05 Feb 2022 10:51:22.289 * Background RDB transfer started by pid 2706728
3829405:M 05 Feb 2022 10:51:27.991 * Marking node fc8e0258e3700c5fde1e3c0487ac1841718db33a as failing (quorum reached).
3829405:M 05 Feb 2022 10:51:30.408 * Clear FAIL state for node fc8e0258e3700c5fde1e3c0487ac1841718db33a: replica is reachable again.
2706728:C 05 Feb 2022 10:58:46.389 * RDB: 1064 MB of memory used by copy-on-write
3829405:M 05 Feb 2022 10:58:46.389 # Diskless rdb transfer, done reading from pipe, 1 replicas still up.
3829405:M 05 Feb 2022 10:58:48.963 * Background RDB transfer terminated with success
3829405:M 05 Feb 2022 10:58:48.963 * Streamed RDB transfer with replica 172.16.0.3:6384 succeeded (socket). Waiting for REPLCONF ACK from slave to enable streaming
3829405:M 05 Feb 2022 10:58:50.021 * Marking node fc8e0258e3700c5fde1e3c0487ac1841718db33a as failing (quorum reached).
3829405:M 05 Feb 2022 11:01:50.058 * Clear FAIL state for node fc8e0258e3700c5fde1e3c0487ac1841718db33a: replica is reachable again.
3829405:M 05 Feb 2022 11:01:50.751 * Synchronization with replica 172.16.0.3:6384 succeeded
```

Redis config (similar for all nodes)

```
bind 172.16.0.1
protected-mode yes
port 6380
tcp-backlog 511
timeout 300
tcp-keepalive 300
daemonize yes
supervised no
pidfile "/var/run/redis/redis-server-6380.pid"
loglevel notice
logfile "/var/log/redis/redis-server-6380.log"
databases 16
always-show-logo no
#save 900 1
#save 300 10
#save 60 10000
stop-writes-on-bgsave-error yes
rdbcompression yes
rdbchecksum yes
dbfilename "dump.rdb"
dir "/var/lib/redis-6380"
replica-serve-stale-data yes
replica-read-only no
repl-diskless-sync yes
repl-diskless-sync-delay 1
repl-disable-tcp-nodelay no
replica-priority 100
maxclients 10000
maxmemory 0
maxmemory-policy noeviction
lazyfree-lazy-eviction no
lazyfree-lazy-expire no
lazyfree-lazy-server-del no
replica-lazy-flush no
appendonly yes
appendfilename "appendonly.aof"
appendfsync everysec
no-appendfsync-on-rewrite no
auto-aof-rewrite-percentage 100
auto-aof-rewrite-min-size 64mb
aof-load-truncated yes
aof-use-rdb-preamble yes
cluster-enabled yes
cluster-config-file "nodes-6380.conf"
cluster-node-timeout 5000
slowlog-log-slower-than 500000
slowlog-max-len 128
latency-monitor-threshold 0
notify-keyspace-events ""
hash-max-ziplist-entries 512
hash-max-ziplist-value 64
list-max-ziplist-size -2
list-compress-depth 0
set-max-intset-entries 512
zset-max-ziplist-entries 128
zset-max-ziplist-value 64
hll-sparse-max-bytes 3000
stream-node-max-bytes 4kb
stream-node-max-entries 100
activerehashing yes
client-output-buffer-limit normal 0 0 0
client-output-buffer-limit replica 20gb 10gb 0
client-output-buffer-limit pubsub 32mb 8mb 60
hz 10
dynamic-hz yes
aof-rewrite-incremental-fsync yes
rdb-save-incremental-fsync yes
user default on nopass ~* +@all
repl-timeout 300
cluster-require-full-coverage no
repl-diskless-load swapdb
```

[Screen from zabbix](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PVYJn.png)

What is possible to check and to fix?

Answer (score 0):

One possible situation is that your master Redis server is too busy and the RDB transfer/load on this slave is slow.

You can resolve this problem by increasing the Replication Buffer Limit.

> Replication buffers are memory buffers that hold data while a slave Redis server synchronizes with the master server.

For fixing the problem, you can see the output of:

```
"config get client-output-buffer-limit"
```

If the output is as follows:

```
1) "client-output-buffer-limit"

2) "normal 0 0 0 slave 268435456 67108864 60 pubsub 33554432 8388608 60"
```

You can increase the buffer limit like this:

```
config set client-output-buffer-limit "slave 10737418240 10737418240 60"
```

P.s: the command should run on the master node

[for more information you can see this blog post about replication buffer](https://redis.com/blog/top-redis-headaches-for-devops-replication-buffer/)